# Overwriting core functionality

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, overrides

As part of a tutorial, I've been asked to overwrite the `getCustomerName()` function in `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data`

I have already created the override class, a etc file to make my module active, and a config file to point to the overwrite file:

`/etc/modules/Skit_Customer.xml` :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Skit>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Skit>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`code/local/Skit/Customer/etc/config.xml` :

```
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <data>Skytiger_Customer_Helper_Data</data>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

`code/local/Skit/Customer/Helper/Data.php` :

```
<?php
class Skytiger_Customer_Helper_Data extends Mage_Customer_Helper_Data
{
    /**
     * Overridden function
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        echo ucwords($this->getCustomer()->getName());
    }
}
```

I have already confirmed that Magento is picking up my overridden function and using it(I put a `die(__CLASS__)` in it. What I want to do now is make sure that my function actually works the way I intended it to (It needs to return the customer's name as all capitals).

Looking at my code, I can see that there shouldn't be any problems, but I would still like to actually test it.

I couldn't find where on the front or back end this function was being called, so when I tested it I made a `test.php` file in the webserver root:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$customerModel = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(2);
$customerHelper = Mage::helper('customer');
$customerHelper->getCustomerName();
```

This works just fine when testing with a `die();`, but I want to test it with an actual customer. I do not know how to make the `test.php` file, or my overridden file, think that there is a customer.

Could anyone please help me figure this out, or at least point me in the right direction?

I wouldn't mind checking it out on the front/back -end, wherever it is called, but I also would really like to know how to create an instance of a customer that I can test with, as it will most likely come in handy in the future.

Comment: Please note to make things uppercase in PHP you need to use the strtoupper() function not ucwords()

Comment: @user2200113 Thanks, but in this case I actually want the first letter of each word to be uppercased, not the entire string :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->getCustomer()` retrieves the customer from the current session:

```
/**
 * Retrieve logged in customer
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 */
public function getCustomer()
{
    if (empty($this->_customer)) {
        $this->_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    }
    return $this->_customer;
}
```

So in your test script, you have to simulate the customer session:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomer($customerModel);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know. I have 5 more minutes before I can accepted your answer, will do it ASAP.'

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look on these files:

> /app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/invoice_new.html -> line 35
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml ->
>   line 34
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml
>   -> line 28 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Giftmessage.php
>   -> line 138 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Giftmessage.php
>   -> line 141 /app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/creditmemo_new.html -> line 35 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Recurring/Profile/View.php -> line 301 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php -> line 425 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php -> line 496
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml ->
>   line 28 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php -> line 799
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php -> line 872
>   /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
>   -> line 120 /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
>   -> line 122 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo.php -> line 755 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo.php -> line
>   828 /app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/shipment_new.html -> line
>   36 /app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/creditmemo_update.html ->
>   line 30 /app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html -> line
>   35 /app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_update.html -> line 30
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php -> line 1288
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php -> line 1357
>   /app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/invoice_update.html -> line 30
>   /app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/shipment_update.html -> line 30

These are the file where this `getCustomerName()` function is called.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful - how did you get this list? Although I appreciate your answer I am marking the other answer as accepted since it directly addresses my query.